# Flutter: Changing of lifecycle causes a re-build of page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have one page active in my app (main page, sole route) and I have not pushed any other pages onto the route stack.

Whenever my app goes into paused mode (only testet on iOS so far) my page gets rebuilt multiple times (mostly 2 time, sometimes up to 5 times).

In the original app the page contains a flutter_inappwebview and that does not seem to like that, as it tries to make https fetches then, that of course fail (in the background) and when I call the app to the foreground again, I see a blank page in the inappwebview.

In my test app I replaced the inappwebview with a simple Text to check if maybe the inappwebview plays a part - it did not, same result.

Why would a change of life cycle, especially going **into** paused mode, cause a re-building of the current page in Flutter?

I would understand that Flutter initiates a rebuild when coming to the foreground again (lifecycle -> resumed) - but when going into paused??

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: I just mentioned the GetX part for completeness - but if you think that GetX is causing this:

I created a test app, no GetX whatsoever, just one page (stateful widget plus state) containing the inappwebview.

Exact same behaviour: Every time the app goes into the background, the build method is called at least twice...

Comment: To avoid similar notes I now also removed the inappwebview from the test app - just a plain page with a simple Text on it - same result. I will amend my initial question and remove all references to GetX and inappwebview as they clearly do not come into it.